# How to read Map-Report in FPGA Synthesis Tools

Tags: fpga, synthesis, lattice

I have this Map-Report piece product by Lattice Diamond:

```
...
 Number of SLICEs:  9609 out of 33264 (29%)
    SLICEs(logic/ROM):  8814 out of 26460 (33%)
    SLICEs(logic/ROM/RAM):  795 out of 6804 (12%)
         As RAM:  795 out of 6804 (12%)
         As Logic/ROM:  0 out of 6804 (0%)
....
```

I already know what means the first line (`Number of SLICEs`), but I can't figure out what the rest means; can someone explain precisely the difference between `SLICEs(logic/ROM)` and `SLICEs(logic/ROM/RAM)`?

I have downloaded dozens of manual, but where can I find more info about all the other report voices?

Comment: @Paebbels Hey man, can you cool it on all of the tag editing?  The entire front page is full of old FPGA questions.  I get its still organization but you are drowning out all of the new questions that still need help.

Comment: @Funkyguy Oh, sorry. I was not aware that all these posts got listed on the front page in topmost position.

Answer (score 2):

These are defined in details in the document:

[LatticeXP2 Family Data Sheet](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~greenwd/lattice_fpga.pdf)

If you go down to "Table 2-1. Resources and Modes Available per Slice" you will find the detailed description of how these slices are used and what kind of terminology they use when reporting the usage of them.

Let me know if this is OK, or I add more data to the answer to clarify it further